# Not receiving sign in email with firebase email link authentication on some emails

Tags: javascript, firebase, email, firebase-authentication

I have firebase email link authentication configured as it is told in the docs. But a few users don't get the sign in email. Why is this happening. One of my friends tried to login with one email and didn't get the email. He then tried with another email and it worked.

I am also not getting an email on some of my emails.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase makes no distinction based on the email addresses. Most likely the message got marked as spam for some of your friends. Have them check the spam box of their mail client, and any spam filters they have on their network.

Also see my answer here for some (progressively involved) workarounds: [Why did this code fail to send password reset link in firebase (Reactjs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922475/why-did-this-code-fail-to-send-password-reset-link-in-firebase-reactjs/72922603#72922603)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think the issue is that mails get sent late to some emails, usually after 10-15 minutes.

Comment: That could be. There is no guaranteed order of delivery or anything like that. If you want better control of the delivery of the emails, you can consider setting up your own SMTP server as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008278/how-do-i-connect-a-smtp-with-firebase

Comment: Ok! But is there a guarantee that the mail will be delivered at some time or not?

Comment: There is a guarantee that the email will be sent (unless there's an outage). There's no way for Firebase to guarantee delivery, as there are many point of failure along the way that are outside Firebase's control. If you select your own SMTP provider, you can better control the points of failure.

Comment: Okay, thank you!