# Why did this code fail to send password reset link in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase and I am trying to handle firebase user authentication in React.js. I did manage to create users with email and passwords. But, now I would like to send the user an Email link to reset their password.

My code currently look like this.

```
// This line of code belongs to the top
import { auth } from '../firebaseConfig'

//This part goes under the React component
    <p onClick={async () => {
      try{
        await sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, // My Email Id)
        alert('Password reset link has been sent to your email')
      }
      catch(err){
        alert(err)
      }
    }}
    >Forgot your Password ?</p>
```

However, I do not get any error messages and I do get the alert message that says "Password reset link has been sent to your email." Unfortunately, I didn't receive any email. Note that I have given my own email id as the parameter for testing purposes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*firebaser here*

Did you check your spam folder? We recently see a lot of the emails from Firebase Authentication ending up in the user's spam folder or being marked as spam in a system along the way. This is being tracked in this [status message](https://status.firebase.google.com/incidents/LqqtfhaYsmNsYe5QpYic) on the Firebase dashboard and in [public issue #253291461](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/253291461).

To reduce the chances of the messages getting marked as spam, consider taking more control of the email delivery yourself.

1. As a first step, consider [using a custom domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/email-custom-domain) with your project. Email that comes from a custom domain has less chance of being marked as span.
2. As a second step, consider [setting up your own SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008278/how-do-i-connect-a-smtp-with-firebase#:%7E:text=You%20can%20set%20a%20custom,to%20log%20into%20smtp2go%20with).) for delivering the email, so that the emails are not being delivered from Firebase's shared infrastructure anymore.

While these steps are more involved, they typically will drastically reduce the cases where the messages from Firebase Authentication are marked as spam.

Answer (score 1):

### Full Guide Based on Frank's Answer

Firstly create a new email account you can use to relay the Firebase emails through the SMTP server with. I personally chose *Gmail*, but I tested with *Outlook* and it also works.

You can now find an SMTP server host that will work for your scenario. If you're sending less than 1000 emails per month you can find *free* and *reliable* hosts. I chose `SMTP2GO`'s free option.

Now you've found the SMTP host, add the email address you've chosen as a `single sender email` (note that if you **do own a domain**, you can alternatively use that to send emails).

[image]

Note that you will have to verify the email, usually by your host sending a link to the email's inbox. Make sure to check spam.

Once verified, navigate to where you host allows you to add `SMTP Users` and add a new user. This will allocate an SMTP `username` and `password`.

[image]

Navigate to the Firebase console, and choose the `Authentication` option from the sidebar (within the Build product category).

Go to `Templates` → `SMTP Settings` and enter the details of your SMTP server. The username and password fields are to be filled with the SMTP user login you created in the step above.

[image]

It is better to use `TLS`, but I believe `SSL` should work too but it is **untested**.

Click save, and you're all set up - but *there may still be steps to perform* depending on your email provider.

---

### Provider Specific Steps

If the emails are being sent to an account managed by Google you will have no issues with your emails being quarantined by anti-spam policies and **it will work immediately**.

If you are using Outlook, you will have a different problem on your hands. Outlook's built in defender will most likely have auto-quarantined your email under **multiple policies** - that bit is important.

These policies are likely to be both *spam* and *phish* policies. If you unblock one of them, the other **will** catch it and re-quarantine.

Unblock both policies for the email address, and test. You can see the status of quarantined messages in Microsoft 365 Defender app under `Review` → `Quarantine`. *Please note* that you will need to be an **administrator** to add global allow policies to your email accounts.

If this still doesn't work it is likely that your company has an additional external filter (as mine did), and you will have to add the IP's manually to the `Tenant Allow/Block Lists` spoofed senders tab.

Comment: This option worked right away for me. Simply use the SMPT setup.

Comment: Glad it was useful