# Firebase Reset Password Link (Did not receive) using firebase react native what's wrong in my code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication

Firebase Reset Password Link (Did not receive)  using firebase react native

```
import {   sendPasswordResetEmail } from '@firebase/auth'
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';

 const onForgot = async  (email) => {
        const auth = firebase.auth();
        await  sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, email)
        .then(() => {
            alert("reset email sent to " + email);
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        });
      }

please help, and thanks in advance.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why did this code fail to send password reset link in firebase (Reactjs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922475/why-did-this-code-fail-to-send-password-reset-link-in-firebase-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how it works in react native. But in reactjs, the way we instantiate the auth is different from what I'm seeing here. We do something like this:

```
import Firebase from "../../Firebase/Firebase";

var auth = getAuth(Firebase);

//some code here e.g. your main function etc

sendPasswordResetEmail(auth, user.email)
                    .then(() => {
                        message.success("Password reset email sent!")
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        message.error("Unable to send reset password link :: " + error.message)
                    });
```

Just verify whether you are indeed getting your "auth" instantiated in the right way here. A simple import doesn't cut it.

EDIT: My code is using version 9 of firebase. Please check with the version you are using and make sure your auth is being instantiated right according to the version

EDIT 2: Remember to enable firebase auth "email sign in" in the firebase console authentication section

All the best.

Comment: i try but,it's not working

Comment: verify whether the auth is enabled in your console. is email and password enabled in your console?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not getting an error back from the call to `sendPasswordResetEmail`, there is likely nothing wrong with your code. More likely the message *was* sent, but got stuck in a spam filter or spam box. So check your spam folder to see if the message showed up there.

Comment: Thanks, i check spam folder and i recevied email , Thank you.