# Firebase reset password not sending link to email in Firebase Console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently having a bug with my Firebase application.
When I use the Firebase reset password feature (on the Firebase console or in the app) I don't get a email sent to my email address.

[image]

The email is the correct one and even with other email addresses I don't get a confirmation email.
[image]

Is there anyway to solve it?

Comment: Did you check the spam folder of your mail client? 
 Many messages from Firebase are ending up in spam filters. To see the possible workarounds, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922475/why-did-this-code-fail-to-send-password-reset-link-in-firebase/72922603#72922603

Comment: Yup, I had a look through "all" section of my email client.