# Is there any problem with firebase authentication?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there any problem with Firebase authentication?
I am not receiving any email (verification or reset) from yesterday.
**I can't even send reset email from console manually**
I have checked spam folder also.
Here is my code

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
                        //is called
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    });
```

Above code worked before, but recently I am facing this issue. I have tried to send reset password to an email through `firebase authentication` manually, but it's not working even.
More info:
If I add user manually and send email, it shows `email sent successfully`. But I don't receive any mail.

Comment: Have you tried to log the error message that exists inside the `e` object, to see if something went wrong?

Comment: `addOnSuccessListener` is being called. Besides, I can't send mail through `console` manually

Comment: So if the `onSuccess` fires. then what is the issue?

Comment: I am not receiving any mail.

Comment: You should wait a few moments after you perform the operation. Always make sure you are checking the right email, meaning the email in the `.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)` is the same as the one you're verifying in the browser. Take a look again at the spam folder, it may accidentally arrive there a bit late.

Comment: No mail in spam folder. I have checked this and also mentioned in question. Suppose my code is wrong, But I can't even send through console in browser.

Answer (score 0):

If the API call succeeds, the email was sent successfully. If it doesn't show up where you expect it, it got lost along the way - typically in a spam filter or a spam folder.

Spam filters are common on large company infrastructure. To check whether the message got caught in such a spam filter, you'll have to check with any IT team that owns part of the delivery infrastructure along the way.

An easier way to check might be to send to a public mail provider, such as Gmail. If the message shows up in the spam **folder** there, you know your code is working correctly. To prevent it getting caught as spam, have a look at my answer here: [Why did this code fail to send password reset link in firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922475/why-did-this-code-fail-to-send-password-reset-link-in-firebase-reactjs)

Comment: But I am not getting email in spam also. Beside I have tried with a temporary mail(`@nezid.com` and `@dmtubes.com`), it doesn't even work there also

Comment: Not even getting mail with `@yandex.com` and `@yahoo.com`.

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much more we can do to troubleshoot here: if the API call succeeds, an email was sent to the address you indicated. If it doesn't show up, it got lost somewhere along the way - but we can't say where that is beyond the options I listed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It was working before. I think from yesterday, I am getting this issue. Where can I contact for solving this issue?

Comment: You can [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting, but (unless there's an issue that I'm not aware off) I expect them to tell you the same as I did here.

Comment: How do I solve then? Is there anything you would suggest me to follow that might help

Comment: I think I have found the issue not solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74330072/firebase-authentication-email-is-not-being-sent-in-default-action-url