# Firebase authentication email goes to spam when started using a custom domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this case where when I switched to production and all the sudden all firebase auth emails go to spam, I rest all setting back to default yet it keeps happening, any idea how to fix this I mean before it was working like charm and all of it went to the main box.. now it goes to spam.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what switching to production means here, but all email goes through the same infrastructure, so it's unlikely there's much you can do in the project itself. As said in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922475/why-did-this-code-fail-to-send-password-reset-link-in-firebase/72922603#72922603), the only additional step **you** can take at the moment is to use a custom SMTP server.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen will this wreck my current google auth or emails will just funnel through different channel ? I mean this is kinda bad, why would this work in testing once I add my custom domain every thing go to spam...