# Does email sending functionality work in development local builds of react firebase projects?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, email, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've created functionality to send a password reset email from this guide.

My code throws no errors and says that it sends the email to a valid email address but I receive no email.

The only reason I could think of that may cause this is that its running on a react local development build instead of the live build website.

Is it the case that firebase email functionality doesn't work on local builds?

---

I have checked my spam folder, checked filtering settings on multiple email addresses. It has no reason to be blocked by my inbox settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is looking for the answer to this question, its yes - email sending functionality does work in local builds.

This turned out to be a very complex solution with a long answer, and was not to do with React at all.

Read Frank's answer, and my guide on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922475/why-did-this-code-fail-to-send-password-reset-link-in-firebase/75161846#75161846).