# Password reset emails from Firebase / Google Identity Platform REJECTED

Tags: firebase, email, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

Some major email providers like GMX and mailbox.org reject the password reset emails from Firebase / Google Identity Platform.

I've set a custom domain, re-implemented the password reset link etc, to avoid having firebaseapp.com in the domain or email body.

The domain which actually sends the email is Google's server. As a developer I just point my DNS to their server. Not sure what additional things I can do?

The server which sends the email is
idp.ctolarsson.com

I've added these DNS records. Google and Gmail is very happy and deliver it straight into the Primary tab, and displays verified padlock.

I'd rather not start randomly testing things as the service is live and 95%+ of people do get the password reset email.

Any insight would be very appreciated! Thanks

[image: DNS Records as per Google/Firebase]

[image]

Comment: Setting up a custom domain usually works, but if it doesn't, the only alternative is to send the messages through your own SMTP server. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922475/why-did-this-code-fail-to-send-password-reset-link-in-firebase/72922603#72922603