# How to set up Firebase authentication with my own SMTP?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Follow instruction from `@FrankvanPuffelen` at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51010891/13446366).
I tried to set up my own SMTP server from Firebase authentication for sending emails as password reset but my SMTP server doesn't send anything after I request to reset a password.

Below is my setup:

```
Sender address: support@contact.example.com
SMTP server host: contact.example.com
PORT: 587 (I also try port 465)
Account: support@contact.example.com
Password: *********
SMTP security mode: STARTTLS (I also try SSL)
```

I tried changing ports, and security mode but I still can't receive anything (nothing from Inbox and also nothing from the Spam folder).

If I use Nodemailer to send emails, my SMTP server works fine with additional `tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }`

Can anyone help me?